# Showing table records in a report with different textboxes

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, report

I have a table name is Table1 with 2 fields which are Name and Married_Status.
For Name includes Names of the employees and for the Married_Status includes Yes or No.
The Question is: Can I show them in a report by 2 ways? first when the status is Yes 2 textboxes appear but if the status in No 1 textboxes appears?
I use Access 2016

Comment: Can use an expression in textbox to show Null based on some condition. Or VBA code can set Visibility property. Not really enough info to provide specific answer. A report with only 2 fields?

Comment: Your user form is designed to show one dataset. Therefore it needs 2 text boxes. Your report is designed to show a list. If the list includes status information it needs 2 columns unless you produce separate lists of married and unmarried people. Neither of the columns would show a text box. A column can be made to display whatever you want, based upon what's in the underlying database. Your question indicates that you might be conflating "report" with "database". Excel is more suitable for that kind of reporting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No I am not conflating, I asked my question in a simple way. My project is too big I can not display all my work but my question is the smallest part of my database. 
I mean how can I make 2 different view in one report ?

Comment: For example in my report sometimes view 2 textboxes sometimes  1 according to the table record.

Comment: Edit question to provide sample data and desired output as text tables. Did you try what I suggested in first comment?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly you want to hide the Married_Status column if it is no.   However this answer covers hiding other columns if I am misunderstanding.  In short, this is called conditional formatting and is done by highlighting the control-clicking the format tab- then clicking conditional formatting.  However, access can only conditionally format the text color, font, and background of a control.  Further the default control for a yes/no variable is a checkbox and the checkbox allows no conditional formatting.
There are two work-arounds. First you can make the Married_Status text box invisible in all cases:
base the report on a query and replace Married_Status with a Calculated variable like:

```
Married_Status: IIf([Table1].[Married_Status]=True,"Married",Null)
```

If we use a text box for Married_Status and make it transparent we get:

[image]

When Married_Status is Null and the Married_Status textbox is transparent nothing shows.  Unfortunately a checkbox shows even when the value is null.

The second work-around requires you know a lot about the data in advance and should only be done if the boss insists.  You can build the report using VBA.  For my sample data I know I have one page of 4 cases so I can avoid the detail section which limits me to one control for every instance of Married_Status and put as many controls as I need in the Header:

[image]

Then in the load event use vba to set the controls:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Table1")
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
rs.MoveFirst
    For i = 1 To 4
Me.Controls("Text" & i) = rs("EmployeeName")
If rs("Married_Status") = True Then
Me.Controls("Check" & i) = True
Else
Me.Controls("Check" & i).Visible = False
End If
rs.MoveNext
    Next i
    End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]